# How to plot trendlines on multiple line plot?

Tags: python, hue, linegraph, trendline

I have a graph depicting the monthly demand over a two year period for 3 different products ('C1 beans', 'C1 nuts', 'A3 Salad'). Note the products have blank spaces in their name and I am not allowed to change the productnames. For each of the 3 products I want to add a trendline to the graph so one can easily see whether there is a decreasing or increasing demand. Up to now I have the following:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
sns.lineplot(data=productdemand, x="month", y="demand", hue="product")
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

The productdemand dataframe looks like this:

```
month  demand  product
04/19  300     C1 beans
04/19  200     C1 nuts
04/19  600     A3 Salad
05/19  250     C1 beans
05/19  200     C1 nuts
05/19  800     A3 Salad
```

How to add the 3 trendlines?

Comment: Can you share a sample from your data in the text form?

Comment: Is the edit above sufficient?

Comment: Can you try lmplot :  `sns.lmplot(data=df, x="month", y="demand", hue="product")` ? Also, there is a typo `plt.xtricks`  should be `plt.xticks`. If it works then I will add an answer.

Comment: Thank you but I really need a line graph with trendline instead of a scatterplot with trendline.

Comment: Okay. Added an answer. please plot lmplot before lineplot.  Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to combine both `lmplot` and `lineplot` to do this. Here is an example with a different dataset:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

#lmplot should be plotted first
sns.lmplot( x='total_bill', y='tip',  hue='smoker', scatter=False, data=tips)
sns.lineplot( x='total_bill', y='tip', hue='smoker',  data=tips, legend=False)
plt.legend([],frameon=False)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That is a nice idea indeed though I get the error - AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'conjugate' - . This is an error I don't get when using sns.lineplot only. Could this be due to the blank spaces in the names of the products?

Comment: Yeah. That seems to be true. Perhaps you can try removing white space using `df['product']  = df['product'].str.map(lambda x : x.strip())`. Then, you can legend name manually in the plt.legend.

Comment: That results in the following error: 'StringMethods' object has no attribute 'map'

Comment: Sorry. There was a problem with my code. Try this : `df['product'] = df['product'].str.strip()` or This should also work : `df['product'] = df['product'].astype(str).map(lambda x : x.strip())`

Comment: Indeed, I see there are no blank spaces in the product names anymore but I still get the AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'conjugate' when calling sns.lmplot .

Comment: Try removing white space from the column names too with : `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip().` If it doesn't work,  Can you perhaps add exact representative data? So, I can reproduce the error. The error is clearly because of whitespaces.

Comment: There is no white space in the column names.

Comment: I am afraid then I can't help without seeing the true representative data.

Comment: No problem. If my answer partially helped you, you can upvote it. You don't need to accept it since, it didn't solve it fully. Perhaps you can ask the question again with my updated code.